# How to disable macOS shortcut “command + right click” which triggers Mission Control?

Tags: macos, macos-monterey, magic-mouse, magic-trackpad

How can I disable macOS shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd> + right click which triggers Mission Control?

I looked in “System Preferences > Mission Control and Keyboard shortcuts” but can't find it defined anywhere. Maybe it's in some plist?

It triggers `Mission Control` (show all application windows).

Comment: I just realised you said cmd/r click… there's no such thing, afaik...

Answer (score 0):

It's in System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Mission Control.

It's  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>↑</kbd>   by default.

[image]

Comment: No, it is F3 and can't be disabled

Comment: @DATEx2 - I see you eventually found I was right… https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/412565/85275